# How do I rewrite URL for query string url in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, url-routing

I trying to create SEO friendly urls in an existing Code igniter application.I could find a no of query string urls and i need it to convert it SEO friendly.

I want to rewrite the following url

for. e.g :

***http://example.com/en/properties?id_categories=3&sub_categories=65&sub_categories2=5391***

to seo friendly as follows :

***http://example.com/en/properties/residential-for-rent***

Please guide me to fix this.

Comment: Hmm, you should read the manual. Because CodeIgniter works using URL like `www.domain.com/controller/parameter`.

Comment: I'm sorry,I am a drupal dev and new to code-igniter.

Comment: Hi @Harikris, can you please tell me how did you do it. Am also trying to do the same but confused how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read this document about URI Routing carefully: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html

Something like:

```
$route['properties/(:any_properties_slug)'] = "properties/get";
```

Then you can put your code into  controller Properties::get() to lookup property by any_properties_slug